# I have preview on UIMenu with reactions and it doesnt scroll and answer on dedSelectItemAt

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview, uicollectionviewcell, uimenu

[the sample of how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcV3j.png)

I have preview on UIMenu with reactions and it doesnt scroll and answer on dedSelectItemAt. It should have a horizontal scrolling but it doesnt response on any touch

this is how I show it on my ReactionsViewController

```
collectionView.delegate = self
collectionView.dataSource = self
collectionView.isScrollEnabled = true
collectionView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
collectionView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = true
        
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffect.Style.dark)
let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
collectionView.frame = view.bounds
collectionView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
view.addSubview(collectionView)
```

this is how I implement it on UIMenu

```
let configuration = UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: identifier, previewProvider: {
            let customView = ReactionsViewController()
            customView.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 250, height: 30)
            customView.onReaction = { [weak self] reactionType in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                print(reactionType)
                self.dismiss(animated: true)
            }
```